# Изменение размеров слайдера-карусели

Tags: jquery

На странице сделан слайдер, но он вылезает за границы страницы, и крайние пункты слева и справа обрезаются. 
http://strdv.inetech.ru/
Где нужно поменять размеры, чтобы всё выводилось по размеру страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в CSS

```
.jcarousel-container {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Да я уже разобралась. Вот такой стиль прописать надо было:

    <style type=\"text/css\">
    
    div.subcolumns{
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%!important;
    }
    </style>

Comment: Не уверен нужно ли стили применять к div.subcolumns - не знаю полного назначения этого дива. Для карусели достаточно применить стили к div.jcarousel-container. И стили у вас избыточные.

 display:inline-block; width: 100%!important; position: relative; - для чего ?

Comment: А div.subcolumns это и есть контейнер, в котором лежит карусель.
Со стилями поиграю, ненужное уберу.

Comment: Да, действительно, достаточно div.subcolumns{overflow: hidden;}, всё остальное избыточно.